# Minecraft 1.17.1 How to Summon a Falling Block: (piston[extended=true])?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I tried the following command:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:piston",Properties:{extended:true}},Time:-1000,NoGravity:1b}
```

but it wasn't the type of piston that I want to summon.

Here is what I am looking for
[image: Here is what I am looking for]

Comment: I think it's off-topic and should be on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: its off topic, but the answer is to write `"true"` instead of `true`: `summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:piston",Properties:{extended:"true"}},Time:-1000,NoGravity:1b}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `"true"` instead of `true`

This is the command to do it:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:piston",Properties:{extended:"true"}},Time:-1000,NoGravity:1b}
```

(tested in 1.17, find by Ofek)